# What are the odds of sitting next to the same person on two flights?

Tags: probability

My wife left on a business trip this morning. 20 people from the same company caught two consecutive flights. Each person checked in independently, yet my wife ended up sitting next to the same colleague on both flights!

What are the odds?

Assume both aeroplanes had 150 seats, in 3+3 configuration, in 25 rows. It's not exactly right but will do for the purposes of the exercise.
Assume also that all other passengers checked in independently, so there are no couples choosing or being assigned seats next to each other, thus changing the odds. This isn't right either, but will also do for the purposes of the exercise.

My wife and colleague were sitting next to each other, not across the aisle from each other.

Comment: An important assumption is missing: That the seats are assigned uniformly randomly. (That may well not be the case, e.g. they may have ordered certain meals, or the colleague may have requested a window seat, etc.)

Comment: Colin, you should familiarize yourself with the well-known "birthday problem", as one aspect of this type of issue.

Comment: @joriki:  It's also conceivable that the seats were all booked at the same time, and as a result the airline assigned all the company's seats in the same part of the plane (since they shared a booking).  As an extreme example, if the company's seats form a block in four rows of the plane, the odds go way up.

Comment: @Fattie: I don't see the connection to the birthday problem.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Except in this case, we manually went in and chose my wife different seats. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your wife has probability $\frac23$ to sit in a chair that has only $1$ chair next to it, and has probability $\frac13$ to sit in a chair that has $2$ other chairs next to it.

The probability that at the first flight your wife had no colleagues sitting next to her is:$$p_0:=\frac23\frac{\binom{148}{19}\binom10}{\binom{149}{19}}+\frac13\frac{\binom{147}{19}\binom{2}{0}}{\binom{149}{19}}=\frac23\frac{130}{149}+\frac13\frac{130\cdot129}{149\cdot148}=\frac{55250
}{66156}\approx0.835147228
$$

The probability that at the first flight your wife had $2$ colleagues sitting next to her is: $$p_2:=\frac13\frac{\binom{147}{17}\binom22}{\binom{149}{19}}=\frac13\frac{19\cdot18}{149\cdot148}=\frac{342}{66156}\approx0.005169599
$$

The probability that at the first flight your wife had exactly $1$ colleague sitting next to her is:$$p_1:=1-p_0-p_2=\frac{10564}{66156}\approx0.159683173
$$

The probability that at the first flight your wife had a colleague sitting next to her, and that this same person was sitting next to her the second flight is:$$p_1\times\left(\frac23\frac1{149}+\frac13\frac2{149}\right)+p_2\times\left(\frac23\frac2{149}+\frac13\left(1-\frac{147}{149}\frac{146}{148}\right)\right)=$$$$\frac{10564}{66156}\frac{4}{447}+\frac{342}{66156}\frac{1182}{66156}=\frac{6658132
}{4376616336
}\approx0.001521$$

Comment: But the people need some decimals.

Comment: You're neglecting the small probability that she had two colleagues sitting next to her on the first flight.

Comment: @joriki thank you for attending me. I will try to fix that.

Comment: @joriki Could you give it a second look please Hawkeye?

Comment: Yes, looks great :-)

Comment: @joriki comforting comment. Thanks!